# Setting up a Backup Exec 10d client access account

Tags: active-directory, backupexec

I'm looking for a way to grant limited access to the BE10d client: basically, I'd like to grant one of my users access to check on a job's status and (a limited number if possible) other BE management features. I know how to install the client already, but I don't want to give him access to the domain administrator. Can anyone point me in the right direction for setting up an account that can access the Backup Exec 10d interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer: simply add the user to the default "Backup Operators" group in AD.